# Vue Router use in services

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have my `vue router` setup for use in external components and services where I setup my router like so:

```js
/* Router.ts */

import { myRoute } from './views/myRoute.vue'

const router = {
routes: [
    {
      name: 'my-router',
      path: '/',
      component: myRoute
    },
}

export default router
```

And inside some services I have a helper method that imports this router in order to work with some query parameters.  The app builds and runs fine, but my unit test that tests my service fails because the router can't find `myRoute.vue` in the 'dist' folder.

```
/myapp/dist/src/router.js:1
Error: Cannot find module './views/myRoute.vue'
```

I'm still fairly new to `Vue`, but I haven't been able to find any documentation or questions regarding this particular issue anywhere, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Why are your tests relying on your build folder? They should be independent of that

Answer (score 0):

Are you declaring `myRoute` as a named export? Standard Vue practice is to use a default export, witch is imported like this

```
import myRoute from './views/myRoute.vue';
```